# Interfacing ratiometric sensor to precision differential ADC

Tags: sensor, adc, differential, interface

Please consider following simplified schematic:

[image: Differential ADC interface]

I'm currently in process of designing the analog interface for prototype heat pump driver/controller. It's job is to measure multiple analog inputs from different devices/sensors as: RTD's, pressure gauges, 4-20mA current loop (remote sensors) and so on. I'm using ADS1248 precision differential ADC. Mainly because it comes with all necessary hardware to deal with RTD's, and multiple external reference inputs give me flexibility with different types of sensors.

My question is specifically about pressure gauges. I'm using [this](https://www.tme.eu/Document/d30db2be3709eea15cf7d7aff66f06ee/MIP-SERIES-EN.pdf) ones. They're ratiometric, they output from 10 to 90% of supply voltage proportionally to measured pressure. The supply voltage is 5V, so from 0,5 to 4,5V. They cannot be directly connected to ADC, it's reference voltage has to be at max Vcc - 1V (so even at Vcc = 5V it wouldn't be enough). Also I would be nice to use full scale of the ADC.

So I devised circuit as shown in the schematic. It converts single ended input to differential signal, and gets rid of the 0,5V offset at minimum pressure, keeping it all referenced to 2/5 of the supply voltage. Bypassing caps, multiplexers and filters are omitted.

I couldn't find much resources online about this particular situation. I took some design hints from LT6350 datasheet (page 13). There is a lot o biasing going on, which I'm not particularly fond of, but it all can be accomplished with only one value of precision resistor.

Is this a good way of doing this? Is there a simpler / more reliable way?
I do understand that such precautions with connecting 1% sensor into 24bit ADC doesn't make much sense. I guess it turned into a design challenge.

Comment: The answer is in the last two sentences of your post, from a practical point of view.